# PyFlink - RabbitMQ sink : A serializer has already been registered for the state; re-registration is not allowed

Tags: python, rabbitmq, apache-flink, pyflink

In PyFlink coding with Python, I am using `Flink 1.15.2` and I source messages from RabbitMQ with the following connector: `flink-sql-connector-rabbitmq-1.15.2.jar`
However, when I try to sink to RabbitMQ with this code, following this link: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/rabbitmq/#installing-rabbitmq

```
stream.add_sink(RMQSink(
    connection_config,      # config for the RabbitMQ connection
    'queueName',            # name of the RabbitMQ queue to send messages to
    SimpleStringSchema()))
```

I got the following error trace:

```
File "/home/ali/.virtualenvs/LAB_920_log_parser_more_investigation-DQLOhTET/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
    details = "Multiplexer hanging up"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1662371359.807069114","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:44295","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":966,"grpc_message":"Multiplexer hanging up","grpc_status":1}"
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ali/.virtualenvs/LAB_920_log_parser_more_investigation-DQLOhTET/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 289, in _execute
    response = task()
```

and more logs here:

```
RuntimeError: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: A serializer has already been registered for the state; re-registration is not allowed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateSerializerProvider$EagerlyRegisteredStateSerializerProvider.registerNewSerializerForRestoredState(StateSerializerProvider.java:344)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.RegisteredKeyValueStateBackendMetaInfo.updateNamespaceSerializer(RegisteredKeyValueStateBackendMetaInfo.java:132)
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding this maping to String as the original datastream contains Tuples:

```
ds_string = stream.map(lambda tuple: tuple[0]+str(tuple[0]), output_type=Types.STRING())
```